# Live Streaming of a music file in Android

Tags: java, android, udp

For learning purpose, I tried creating a client and a server. One person sends the UDP packets of a music file and the other person receives it. I created such an app and the packets are actually being transmitted like i wanted. But the problem is when after receiving a packet, i try to play it, the sound played is nothing but noise. Meaningless sound comes from the speakers.

**To test my process of sending and receiving packets**, I tried replacing the audio file with a **text file** and then check the contents of the packets at the receiver side. What i noticed was that the packets received are **highly random**. I mean they are not in the correct order.

I know in UDP the packets can reach the destination in any order as there is **no error control** or anything. But the question is then how should i get the correct sound out of the speakers. As if the packets transmitted in the order **ABC** and received in the order **BCA** then obviously the sound will never be correct. Is there any way i can convert the byte array of packets into a meaningful sound.

I know **one solution is to use TCP** but TCP is not for live streaming. **For purposes like Live Streaming and video Conferencing, UDP is used.** Now what is the correct way to gather and play the received packets. Any help is appreciated.

**Code for sender:**

```
InputStream songInputStream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/song.mp3");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

try {
    clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
} catch (SocketException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
while ((songInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > -1) {

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,
                            buffer.length, hostInet, serverPort);
                    try {
                        clientSocket.send(packet);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Packet sent to "
                                + serviceInfo.getServiceName().toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Code on Receiver Side:**

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
do {
            try {
                datagramSocket.receive(packet);
                Log.e(TAG,
                        "Recieved packet from IP "
                                + packet.getAddress().toString()
                                + " and port = "
                                + packet.getPort()
                                );

                buffer = packet.getData();



            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
} while (true);
```

Now the buffer contains the packets sent by the sender but they are not coming in the correct order. So how to play the sound using the transmitted packets.

Comment: You need to send a timestamp with each packet. You also need to set some kind of delay time `dt`. Whatever is streamed at time `t`, should be played at time `t+dt`. You use the `dt` interval to gather as many relevant packets as you can, and arrange them in the order of their timestamps. Not all packets will arrive within `dt`, or at all. You will have some missing packets and you will need to play somehow without them. Good luck with tackling that.